# Перевод часов и Redmine

Tags: redmine, ruby

Подскажите, как настроить правильное время в редмайне после перевода часов в октябре?

Северное время соответствует нормальному. А вот время в редмайне спешит на час. Я в руби не силен (точнее вообще полный ноль) и не знаю, как там расчитываются часовые пояса. Я полагаю, что используется внутренняя TimeZoneDB, но не знаю, так ли это. Или же часовые пояса со смещениями жестко вшиты в редмайн.

Так, например, у каждого пользователя в настройках есть выбор часового пояса. И московское время указано со смещением +4. Да, конечно, можно выбрать какой-нибудь пояс со смещением +3, но это не выход.

**Обновление**

Правильно ли я понял, что нужно выполнить следующую команду?

```
gem update tzinfo-data
```

Суть в том, что ничего не изменилось. Время на час вперед спешит. В списке часовых поясов Москва по-прежнему отображается как +4.

`gem list` выводит следующее:

```
tzinfo (1.2.2, 0.3.37)
tzinfo-data (1.2014.9)
```

**Обновление**

Сейчас, видимо, скажу глупость. Но. Как это сделать? ) Я в руби полный ноль (точнее даже минус один).

Залил это в файл 1.rb в корень с редмайном. И выполнил в консоли:

```
ruby 1.rb
```

Получилось вот это:

```
Thu Nov 06 16:00:00 UTC 2014
```

Я правильно сделал? Что-то мне подсказывает, что нет, это я сделал не в контексте редмайна, хоть и, по идее, вывод верный (если я правильно понял синтаксис - 19 часов по МСК - это 16 в UTC).

Список доступных в редмайне временных зон выглядит так: http://prntscr.com/53nw1z

Comment: Что вот этот код выводит в контексте Redmine кода?:

    require 'tzinfo'

    tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('Europe/Moscow')
    puts tz.local_to_utc(Time.local(2014, 11, 6, 19)).to_s

Comment: @jfs сейчас видимо скажу глупость. Но. Как это сделать?) Я в руби полный ноль (точнее даже минус один).

Залил это в файл 1.rb в корень с редмайном. И выполнил в консоли:

  ruby 1.rb

получилось вот это:

  Thu Nov 06 16:00:00 UTC 2014

я правильно сделал? Но, если я правильно понимаю, это я сделал не в контексте редмайна, хоть и по идее вывод верный (если я правильно понял синтаксис - 19 часов по МСК - это 16 в UTC).

Список доступных в редмайне временных зон выглядит так: http://prntscr.com/53nw1z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оказалось всё проще:

```
gem install tzinfo --version 0.3.42
gem uninstall tzinfo --version 0.3.37
```

и перезапустить редмайн.
В общем, совместимость теряется, если меняется основная версия, в данном случае 0. на 1.

Старый метод: Я не нашел ничего лучше, как прямо отредактировать старый гем и добавить в него строку из нового, т.е.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/tzinfo-0.3.37/lib/tzinfo/definitions/Europe/Moscow.rb

tz.transition 2014, 10, :o6, 1414274400
```

строка  tzinfo (1.2.2, 0.3.37) означает, что у вас стоят два гема, но если попробовать удалить старый, то выдаст

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
        tzinfo-0.3.37

activerecord-3.2.13 depends on [tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)] actionpack-3.2.13 depends on [tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)]

из чего можно сделать вывод, что activerecord использует именно его. Дальше разбираться не стал, время в редмайне поправилось.

Answer (score 2):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) написан, используя Ruby on Rails фрэймворк, который использует [TzInfo библиотеку](http://tzinfo.github.io/), чтобы получить информацию о временных зонах.

TzInfo может использовать либо системную zoneinfo ([Olson timezone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html)), либо свой экземпляр (из [tzinfo-data gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/tzinfo-data)).

Если система показывает правильное время, то можно попробовать обновить tzinfo-data джем. Изменения в Московском времени вызваны [федеральным законом от 21 июля 2014 г. N 248-ФЗ](http://graph.document.kremlin.ru/page.aspx?1;3644925), так что версию новее этой даты нужно ставить.

**Обновление**

`16:00` это правильный ответ (MSK+0300), т.е., tzinfo работает как положено. На системе может быть несколько различных реализаций Ruby установлено, набор джемов может быть другим. Что используется для управления версиями руби: rvm, rbenv, chruby? Я не знаком, как redmine изнутри устроен. Догадки: список генерируется без участия tzinfo (это неправильно, так как может привести к устаревшей информации); или `TZInfo::DataSource.set` указывает на устаревшее zoneinfo (маловероятно); tzinfo-data или не используется или устаревший в окружении redmine. Последнее можно полечить, если обновить redmine.

Answer (score 0):

TimeZoneDB общесистемная. Её и обновите.

Comment: Т.е. общесистемная? На сервере время и часовой пояс указаны верные (соответствуют переведенному).
Проблема именно в редмайне.